# How to retrieve the JSON value from multiple array response data using regular expression extractor in jmeter?

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "responseData":
         {
             "createdDate":"2016-04-23 14:39:35",
             "modifiedDate":"2016-04-23 14:39:35",
             "catalogID":1009
         }
    }
}
```

Here is sample JSON data for reference. I need to extract the value of `catalogID=1009`. How to extract the value of catalogID?? can anyone please share your idea???

What is the regular expression to retrieve the catalogID??

Comment: jmeter allows jsonpath..use that only..its much better option than regex

Answer (score 2):

Use the following regular expression extractor configuration:

- Reference Name: variable name of your choice, i.e. `catalogID`
- Regular Expression: `"catalogID":(\d+)`
- Template: `$1$`

Refer extracted value as `${catalogID}` where required.

Few tips:

1. You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener in RegExp Tester mode to test your regular expressions against real response:

   [image: Regexp Tester]

   See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details.
2. There is [JSON Path Extractor](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) which allows using JSON Path language (more handy than regular expressions when it comes to JSON), for example the relevant query to get "catalogID" will be as simple as:

   ```
   $..catalogID[0]
   ```

   There is also an online [JSON Path Expression Tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: Thanks for ur effort but not working for this Regular Expression: "catalogID":(\d+) . I need to extract inside the array data. can u pls tell me the purpose of template ? and please add the screenshot for regular expression extractor page. I want know how ur gave the reg exp.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, use

```
"catalogID":(.+?)
```

or

```
"catalogID":(\d+) <-- For only digits
```

You can also install the plugin JSONPath for jmeter and use this instead

```
$.response[0].responseData[0].catalogID
```

More **[info](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/)**

Comment: I had used this "catalogID":"(.+?)" reg exp but it was not retrieve the value(1009). Json path extractor is not recommended in my organization.

Comment: @tsivarajan why are using quotes??There are no quotes in input after `:`

Comment: i had tried both ways with quotes and without quotes. but its not working. Verify this link (http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/06/12/parsing-json-responses-with-jmeter/) in here they r using quotes.

Comment: @tsivarajan i think they are using quotes because there is quotes in input they have shown..try to capture any other thing and see if it works

Comment: but i need to extract string as well as integer. can u pls share if u find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for this question.

Here you want to extract the integer value means then use this requalar expression like `"catalogID":(.*?),`

String means `"catalogID":"(.*?)",`

Lets do it!

Comment: This is exactly what I had written in my answer and told you to do in comments and why `,`?

Comment: but u didn't mentioned , (comma). It will show error message without give the ,(comma). I don't no why its required.

Comment: its weird because the other answer also does not have `,`